# Iam trying to use a calendar in django to post events, in this case DJANGO-SCHEDULER(others appears to be outdated), but iam not getting sucess on it

Tags: python, django, calendar, django-scheduler

I followed the steps in github to installed it but its not working, iam with doubts what to do in the models and views

models.py

```
class Programacao(models.Model):
título = models.CharField(max_length=200)
descrição = models.TextField()
data_inicio = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=False, null=True)
data_fim = models.DateField(default=datetime.now, blank=False, null=True)
imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to='imagens/%Y/%m/%d/')
publicado = models.BooleanField(default=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Programação'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Programações'

def __str__(self):
    return self.título
```

Comment: Where you able to solve it? I'm stucked in the same:(